# glpi webservice call returns No response and Bad response

Tags: inventory

I have been working on glpi since a couple of weeks. Whenever I try to call webservice with the command

```
/var/www/html/glpi0.84/glpi/plugins/webservices/scripts$ php testxmlrpc.php --host=127.0.0.1 --url=/glpi0.84/glpi/plugins/webservices/scripts/testxmlrpc.php
```

it returns

```
+ Calling 'glpi.test' on    http://127.0.0.1//glpi0.84/glpi/plugins/webservices/scripts/testxmlrpc.php
+ Calling 'glpi.test' on  http://localhost//glpi/plugins/webservices/xmlrpc.php
+ No response
+ Bad response
```

How can I fix this?Also Is there a way to implement network discovery using ocs coupled with glpi? I have refered to [ocs documentation](http://wiki.ocsinventory-ng.org/index.php/Documentation:Main). I have installed ocsinventory-agent but caling ocs agent with `sudo ocsinventory-agent` and `sudo ocsinventory-agent --server=localhost` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  fixed it myself. The issue was I have to provide the credentials set in glpi webservice plugin not those used to log in to glpi web interface. This can be accessed from

`plugins-->webservices-->local-->username/password`